# Converting newlines to spaces in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm writing a document and I have a few chapter titles that I would like to appear as 2 lines for a chapter title, but only one line in the table of contents. Is there a simple command I to filter out the newline character like this?

Chapter Title

> First Line:
>
> Second more informative line

ToC:

> First Line: Second more informative line

Comment: Did you know there's a dedicated Stack Exchange site for LaTeX (and friends) questions?  It's at tex.stackexchange.com -- check it out!

Answer (score 3):

you can define alternative chapter titles for the toc:

```
\chapter[toc title]{regular title}
```

Comment: Excellent, this will do it. I knew there had to be some way to deal with it that I just wasn't aware of.

Comment: +1 because I learned something new while posting an answer -- I was going to suggest something with adding a TOC line manually because I didn't know chapter took an optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

Building on second's answer above -- adding another answer so I can format the code nicely.

If you want, you can even make your own command.  Something like this:

```
\newcommand{\twolineChapter}[2]{ %
    \chapter[#1: #2]{#1: \\ #2} %
}
```

Then write in your document's body

```
\twolineChapter{First Line}{Second more informative line}
```

Which, when you typeset your book, will get turned into

```
\chapter[First Line: Second more informative line]{First Line: \\ Second more informative line}
```

This is especially nice if you later decide to change how titles are formatted, for example putting the subtitle in a smaller font.